# How do I make .tmp files (of a given size) with batch and Python

Tags: python, batch-file

I am trying to make 20 .tmp files in batch or python. I have been looking through everything and cant find a solution. I want the .tmp files to store in `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Temp` here is the code.

Python:

```
import tempfile
# This makes a .tmp file but only 0kb i want like 37kb
for i in range(20):
    new_file, filename = tempfile.mkstemp('.tmp')
    print(filename)
```

This makes a .tmp file but I want to increase the size/ storage it takes

I don't have a way for batch so please help me all support is appreciative

Comment: I have managed to make .tmp files but how do I increase the size or write in it

Comment: A file's size is that of its *contents*, not available space. To create a file of the size 37Kb, then simply write 37000 bytes of data into the file. Given standard ASCII, this would be approximately 37K characters, (given ~1byte (7 bits to be exact) per character).

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Do you want *random* data written to the files?

Comment: Yes that would be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function below can be used to write (n) bytes of random data into the file specified.

Using the `os.urandom` function, the number of random bytes is generated, and written into the file path specified to the `fpath` function parameter.

Note: As this is binary data, it is not human-readable - but given it's just random data filling the file, that should not matter.

```
def write_temp_file(fpath: str, size: int):
    """Create a temp file filled with (n) random bytes.
    
    Args:
        fpath (str): Full path to the file.
        size (int): Number of bytes to write into the file.
    
    """
    with open(fpath, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(os.urandom(size))
```

Use:

```
>>> write_temp_file('/tmp/tempfile.tmp', 37000)
```

Output:

I'm using Linux, so the file display is a little bit different, but you can see a file has been written of the size 37Kb.

```
$ la /tmp/temp*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 37K Jul 26 11:29 tempfile.tmp
```

---

#### Creating many `.tmp` files:

If you'd like to generate many `.tmp` file, you can wrap the function call in a loop, such as:

```
for i in range(1, 21):
    n = str(i).zfill(2)
    write_temp_file(f'/tmp/tempfile{n}.tmp', 37000)
```

Output:

```
$ la /tmp/temp*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 37000 Jul 26 11:42 /tmp/tempfile01.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 37000 Jul 26 11:42 /tmp/tempfile02.tmp
...
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 37000 Jul 26 11:42 /tmp/tempfile19.tmp
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user group 37000 Jul 26 11:42 /tmp/tempfile20.tmp
```

Comment: write_temp_file(f'"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp"{n}.tmp', 37000)
                                                                ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: You can use: `path = f'{os.getenv("USERPROFILE")}/AppData/Local/Temp/tempfile{n}.tmp'`. Remember to `import os` first.  Use forward slashes as the path separator, as a backslash is an [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Comment: Sry did not know that thanks tho

Comment: It says write_temp_file(path = f'{os.getenv("USERPROFILE")}/AppData/Local/Temp/tempfile{n}.tmp', size=3700)
TypeError: write_temp_file() got an unexpected keyword argument 'path'

Answer (score 1):

Whilst the question has already been answered, and a [python](/questions/tagged/python) solution accepted, the OP did also include the [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag.

For that reason, here is a very basic example of how to generate a dummy file of size `37KB` filled with `_` characters, from a batch file.

```bash
@(For /L %%G In (1,1,37) Do @For /L %%H In (1,1,1024) Do @Set /P "=_" 0<NUL) 1>"%LocalAppData%\Temp\dummy.tmp"
```

Just change the number of kilobytes, currently `37`, *(just before the first closing parenthesis)*, and the fill character, `_`, *(just after the `=` character)*, as needed.

Please note that the above example will be relatively slow, so would be unsuitable for large files.

There are better ways of creating larger dummy files, one of which is often ignored, because historically it required to be 'Run as administrator'. However, certainly in Windows 10, that restriction is no longer in place for the required task, and standard users can benefit from its use. That method involves the built-in utility `fsutil.exe`, which has the ability to very quickly create a file of defined size, including larger ones.

Example: `fsutil file createNew <filename> <length>`

For a 37KB file named `dummy.tmp` in `%SystemDrive%\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp`, *(which is usually, by default, `%TEMP%`, and/or `%TMP%`)*, from a batch file:

```bash
@Set "sizeKB=37"
@Set /A sizeB = sizeKB * 1024
@%SystemRoot%\System32\fsutil.exe file createNew "%LocalAppData%\Temp\dummy.tmp" %sizeB%
```

The downside of this is that you do not have an opportunity to select the content or its format.

---

You could of course leverage other built-in scripting languages from a batch file, VBScript, JScript and PowerShell, but as the OP already has `python.exe` installed, including such things, under this question would be wasted effort.